# What does it mean when a javascript function is called like this func(foo)(bar)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, antd

I often see that a method is called with a second pair of parentheses.

For example the connect function in redux.

```
connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(TodoItem)
```

Or this function from antd

```
const prefixSelector = getFieldDecorator('prefix', {
      initialValue: '86',
    })(
      <Select style={{ width: 70 }}>
        <Option value="86">+86</Option>
        <Option value="87">+87</Option>
      </Select>
    );const prefixSelector = getFieldDecorator('prefix', {
      initialValue: '86',
    })(
      <Select style={{ width: 70 }}>
        <Option value="86">+86</Option>
        <Option value="87">+87</Option>
      </Select>
    );
```

What happens here and how is this concept called so that i can research it further?

Comment: Higher-order function - you can call a function that returns another function

Comment: You don't need to write return, it will return automatically.

Comment: Hi, first of all, thank you for the edit and the links to the  answer to my question. Since im new here, what is the code of conduct here? Should i delete the question since its dublicate or leave it for others to find who use the same wording?

Comment: @JayBee: yes, better to leave this one.